# Custom Scrollbar Positioning

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have a `div` with class `parent`. It has two children `div.title` and `div.body`. `div.body` is scrollable in `y` direction, and `div.title` is fixed at the top of `div.parent` using `absolute` positioning. `div.title` must be a translucent element by design. The problem is that a part of the scrollbars get below `div.title`. See this screenshot :

[image: Scollbar position issue]

And here is the code :

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
}

div.title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 20;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: rgb(0, 50, 200, 0.3);
  color: rgb(0, 50, 200);
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
}

div.body {
  padding-top: 60px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

div.component {
  height: 60px;
  background: black;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="title">
    This is title
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="component"></div>
    <div class="component"></div>
    <div class="component"></div>
    <div class="component"></div>
    <div class="component"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to get the scrollbars like this, but without sacrifising the transparency effect in `div.title` when the content of `div.body` is being scrolled:

[image: Desired scrollbar position]

Comment: Post actual code not picture of code please.  Be sure to include the CSS since that appears to be the crux of this issue.

Comment: Since, the code was very long, I decided not to include it directly in the question, and therefore, I had already provided the link to the playground instead. @MarkSchultheiss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently found that changing a `margin-top` property on the pseudo `-webkit-scrollbar` and similar selectors does it. This works well on Chromium based web browsers.

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
}


div.body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 40px; 
}

div.title {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 20;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: rgb(0, 50, 200, 0.3);
  color: rgb(0, 50, 200);
  border-radius: 8px 0 0 0;
}

div.component {
  height: 60px;
  background: black;
  margin: 10px;
}

.body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

.body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
  margin-top: 44px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #cdcdcd;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="title">This is title</div>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="component"></div>
    <div class="component"></div>
    <div class="component"></div>
    <div class="component"></div>
    <div class="component"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```